# How can I save the edit box data in the GUI Guide?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, editbox

I am making a GUI in which there is a multi-line edit box.

the user will have to input the 3 x-y coordinates in this edit box at a time:

```
[345.567 123.123] 
[390.567 178.098]
[378.000 125.987]
```

by clicking the push button I want these coordinates to be **"saved"** in the Matlab GUI workspace in the form of a *matrix* and by clicking another push button **"reloaded"** from the workspace so that they can be available for future use.

How can I do that?

Can anyone guide me with this? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to [manage data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f5-998352.html) in GUIDE-generated GUIs. The easiest IMO is to use `guidata`.

For example inside the "Save" push button callback, you would access the edit box string contents, parse as matrix of numbers as save it inside the `handles` structure.

```
function pushbuttonSave_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles.M = str2num(get(handles.edit1, 'String'));
    guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

Next in the "load" button, we do the opposite, by loading the matrix from the `handles` structure, converting it to string, and set the edit box content:

```
function pushbuttonLoad_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    s = num2str(handles.M, '%.3f %.3f\n');
    set(handles.edit1, 'String',s)
end
```

[image: screenshot]

If you want to export/import the data to/from the "workspace", you can use the ASSIGNIN/EVALIN function:

```
assignin('base','M',handles.M);
```

and

```
handles.M = evalin('base','M');
```

Comment: thanks Amro for your kind help but what i did is:

`function savepoint_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
user_entry = getappdata(handles.edit1 , 'yourVariable');
v = get(handles.edit1,'String');
matrix= str2num(v);
assignin('base','a',matrix);`

this variable 'a' is stored in the workspace in the form of the matrix like:


a =

    0.3170    0.1272
    0.2849    0.2467
    0.3419    0.3609

but i am not able to perform more operations on 'a'. how can i further use a????

how can i do 
w1= a(1,2)+a(2,2) ??? 

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

to save data:

```
setappdata(h,'name',value)
```

to load data:

```
value = getappdata(h,'name')
values = getappdata(h)
```

where h is the handle you store the data in, name is the variable of the data, value is the actual data.

Comment: Xurtio! my variable 'a' is stored in the workspace. but i am not able to perform further operations on that variable.how can i do that w1= a(1,2)+a(2,2)???

Comment: That sounds more like a problem of scope, but it seems like you're asking a different question now?  If so, you should star a new thread and focus on your original question here.